# regex in php fails

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to fetch this from a file:

```
BEGIN_SEREFERRALS 2 google 13 15 search 2 2 END_SEREFERRALS
```

I use this function:

```
     function getTextBetweenSEO($file)
{
    $pattern = "/BEGIN_SEREFERRALS\s(.*)\sEND_SEREFERRALS/i";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $file, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
    exit();
    return $matches[1];

}
```

What I have printed is this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )
```

why does the regular expression fails

Comment: Must be something else because what you have [just works](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eRUi2n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with this regex :

$pattern = "^BEGIN_SEREFERRALS(.*)END_SEREFERRALS^";

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => BEGIN_SEREFERRALS 2 google 13 15 search 2 2 END_SEREFERRALS
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  2 google 13 15 search 2 2 
        )
)
```

FIX For pattern on blob text data:

$pattern = "/BEGIN_SEREFERRALS(.*)END_SEREFERRALS/";

```
getTextBetweenSEO("jsdfhksdjhskjfdsjfhsdkjfhBEGIN_SEREFERRALS 2 google 13 15 search 2 2 END_SEREFERRALSjklajdakldjaslkdjakldjalkdjalksdj")

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => BEGIN_SEREFERRALS 2 google 13 15 search 2 2 END_SEREFERRALS
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  2 google 13 15 search 2 2 
        )
)
```

Comment: didnt work :(............. why do i need thouse ^^??!? the string Begin... is inside text..so i dont think ^ is relevant

Comment: of course you can remove ^^ is pattern is in glob text data. this oneworking well: $pattern = "/BEGIN_SEREFERRALS(.*)END_SEREFERRALS/";

Comment: I tried that already, and it didnt work for some reason.. I took a piece of code that finds end and start positions between two strings.. no idea why it didnt work...but i guess if you tested it on your example, it works